# About indexes when join 2 columns with int type and varchar type

Tags: mysql, sql, types

```
User.id type INT
Avatar.foreign_key type VARCHAR
```

When I use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN `avatar` ON (`avatar`.`foreign_key` = `user`.`id` )
```

Indexes don't use in this query. Unless I change **User.id**, **Avatar.foreign_key** to same type.

How can I make above query use index that I don't need to change 2 columns type? I want keep VARCHAR and INT on 2 columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They need to be the same type--and they should be anyway.  If you need one of them to be a VARCHAR, and the other to be an INT, that's a sign that you're abusing the VARCHAR column.  You should add a new INT column to your avatar table that can have a proper FK relationship to the other.

Why do you need one of these to be a VARCHAR?

Comment: it because my exist database. Is it impossible to use index on 2 columns with type diffence ?

Comment: The reason the index doesn't work in this case is because before MySQL can do the comparison, it has to convert the VARCHAR into INT, and then the existing VARCHAR index is worthless.  You know you _can_ change a datatype in an existing table--if all of the values of **avatar.foreign_key** can be converted to an INT, a simple ALTER TABLE command should do the trick for you.

Comment: @meotimdihia: Flimzy is correct - MySQL is performing implicit conversion.  Explicit conversion is when you use a function, like CAST/CONVERT or DATE.